# When using foreach with while loop it's showing error in php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a PHP query for select data from database its working. and I'm user **foreach** for print data out of while loop. And it's also working but when I'm trying to select same value with **foreach** it's showing error. I check my code and i right.

**Code id Here**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM user WHERE userid = '205'";
$result = mysqli_query($con_db, $sql);
//Creating array 
$userdata = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $userdata[] =  $row;
    }
}else{
    echo "No Result Found";
}

//Here I'm Showing Data
foreach($userdata as $user) {
    echo $user["useremail"];
}
?>
```

**When i'm Run This Code like**

```
<?php
foreach($userdata as $user) {
    echo "<p>".$user['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
echo "<br><br>";
foreach($userdata as $userdata) {
    echo "<p>".$user['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
?>
```

**This is Result**

```
example@gmail.com

//This is Error
Notice:  Undefined variable: user in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ats\recruiters\recruiter.php on line 111

Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\ats\recruiters\recruiter.php on line 111
```

Comment: you have not declared $sqldata.

Comment: Where and how is `$sqldata` defined?

Comment: refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: edit the error also

Comment: Please Check i update code

Comment: Check the second `foreach` loop you are declaring `$userdata` and accessing with `$user`. I have posted the correct code in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`$sqldata` not declared!

Try this

```
<?php
foreach($userdata as $user) {
    echo "<p>".$user['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
echo "<br><br>";
foreach($userdata as $user) {
    echo "<p>".$user['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: @Deepak try this foreach($userdata as $user) {
    echo "<p>".$user['userloginemail']."</p>";
} instead of foreach($userdata as $userdata) {
    echo "<p>".$user['userloginemail']."</p>";
}

Comment: @Deepak you are using foreach($userdata as $userdata) but you need to change the variable to foreach($userdata as $user). Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not sollution but suggestion that this is silly mistakes that developers do and makes bigger problem So it is good if you learn own self.

> Notice:  Undefined variable: sqldata in

This error mean by That The Defined variable by you is not defined or not a valid .
So First Learn this error **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)**

And

> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

This mean by The Value Supplied in foreach is not valid as per [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) requirement

So kindly check Whetther array is Valid or not by `print_d()`

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no array or variable defined as $sqldata

I think you want this

```
<?php
 foreach($userdata as $sqldata) {
    echo "<p>".$sqldata['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
echo "<br><br>";
foreach($userdata as $sqldata) {
    echo "<p>".$sqldata['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: is the page you running is different from the page you are using the sql ?

Comment: no It's Same but when i'm trying to print same value again its showing error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not passing `$result` to fetch the data.
`$sql` is just the query string not the result that comes out from the query
 Do this instead

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {//pass $result
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {//pass $result
        $userdata[] =  $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "No Result Found";
}
```

Also make sure to check if array is not empty. Use `empty()`

```
if(!empty($userdata)){
  //then loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the second `foreach` loop you are declaring `$userdata` and accessing with `$user`.

Your code:

```
foreach($userdata as $userdata) {
    echo "<p>".$user['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
```

Correct Code:

```
foreach($userdata as $user1) {
    echo "<p>".$user1['userloginemail']."</p>";
}
```